# Unable to assign roles or permissions to user (Laravel - nova permissions)

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-nova

I am using `Laravel 5.7` with `postgreSQL` and `nova` for admin panel. I also use [vyuldashev/nova-permission](https://github.com/vyuldashev/nova-permission) for handling rbac CRUD that is build on top of [spatie/laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission).

Everything in nova permission CRUD is fining when defining permissions or roles. But the problem is when I assign permission or role to a user, I get the following error:

```
[10:50:18] LOG.error: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "id" does not exist
LINE 1: ... "role_id", "model_type")
values
($1, $2, $3) returning "id" ^ (SQL: insert into "model_has_roles" ("model_id", "role_id", "model_type") 
values
 (198564523584, 1, App\Models\User\User) returning "id") {"userId":198564523584,"email":"b.sobhanbagheri@gmail.com","exception":{"errorInfo":["42703",7,"ERROR:  column \"id\" does not exist\nLINE 1: ... \"role_id\", \"model_type\") values ($1, $2, $3) returning \"id\"\n ^"]}}
```

I am not sure what is breaking the query exactly. And if it has anything to do with `postgreSQL`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code how you add the permission to the user?

Comment: @Ruub  I installed this package and everything is happening under the hood. I'm using it in other projects with mysql or mariadb without this issue: https://github.com/vyuldashev/nova-permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem for me has been solved by adding auto increment `id` to the table that I was trying to add record (to the default migrations). seems like `postgreSQL` or `laravel` do not let you to insert to the table that does not have auto increment `id` based on the package code and query structure.